# To generate wordcloud in python jupyter notebook environment

Tags: python-3.x, corpus, word-cloud

I am working corpus analysis for non english text, but I am facing several problem like clustering with k-means 
Now I am facing problem in generating wordcloud in python 3.5.2 jupyter notebook
I installed wordcloud with command pip install wordcloud than process following code

```
# Simple WordCloud
from os import path
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

text = 'all your base are belong to us all of your base base base'
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf',
                      relative_scaling = 1.0,
                      stopwords = 'to of'
                      ).generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

But got following error

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      5 import random
      6 
----> 7 from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
      8 
      9 text = 'all your base are belong to us all of your base base base'

ImportError: No module named 'wordcloud'

plz help me in this concern.

Comment: I removed error but cloud appears does not give complete words. It shows just characters. plz help

Comment: I removed error by installing wordcloud module. Now wordcloud appears but with characters only while I need wordcloud with words. plz help